# Is there a lower bound in the opposite direction of the data processing inequality?

Tags: pr.probability

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ be the distributions of random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively. Let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be the distributions of $T(X_1)$ and $T(X_2)$ respectively, where $T(\cdot)$ is some function. For any f-divergence, $D_{f}(\cdot\|\cdot)$, the data processing inequality gives us $$ D_{f}(g_{1}\|g_{2}) \leq D_{f}(f_{1}\|f_{2}).$$ Are there any known results in the opposite direction in the form $D_{f}(g_{1}\|g_{2}) \geq h(D_{f}(f_{1}\|f_{2})) $ for some function $h(\cdot)$?